# why does if/then not work in relation to document.querySelector? Part of code for a rockscissorpaper game

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a rockscissorspaper game and this part of the code relates to how I will get the users choice. To test it is working I want to first console log the choice.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .rockChoice {
      font-size: 20px;
    }
    
    .scissorsChoice {
      font-size: 20px;
    }
    
    .paperChoice {
      font-size: 20px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="rockChoice isRock"><a href="#">Rock</a></div>
  <div class="scissorsChoice"><a href="#">Scissors</a></div>
  <div class="paperChoice"><a href="#">Paper</a></div>
  <script>
    function checkUserChoice() {
      if (document.querySelector(".rockChoice").classList.contains(isRock)) {
        userChoice = "rock";
      } else if (document.querySelector(".scissorsChoice").classList.contains(isScissors)) {
        userChoice = "scissors";
      } else if (document.querySelector(".paperChoice").classList.contains(isPaper)) {
        userChoice = "paper";
      }
    }

    function checkUserChoice();
    console.log('the user choice is ' + userChoice);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I have a sense of how to code the rest of it but this part should work in isolation.

Answer (score 2):

First problem with your code:

```
function checkUserChoice() {  ... code here ... }  // this is how to define functions
function checkUserChoice();    // that is not how to call functions
checkUserChoice();             // this is the way to call a function
```

Second problem with your code:

```
   ...classList.contains(isPaper)  // this will check if the class list contains a string
                                   // however, you forgot the quotes
                                   // otherwise, JS will think that what you need
                                   // to search for is stored in a variable named isPaper
                                   // which in your case, is not true

 ...classList.contains("isPaper")  // this is what you meant to say
```

Third problem with your code:
**always declare variables, don't just use them on the fly**

```
userChoice = "rock";   // userChoice has never been declared.
                       // it might work, but it is not good practice
```

declaring variables will set their scope (global/private to a function, etc)..

```
var userChoice;   //declare first
function my_function() {
   ...
       userChoice = "something";    // assign later
   ...
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .rockChoice {
      font-size: 20px;
    }
    
    .scissorsChoice {
      font-size: 20px;
    }
    
    .paperChoice {
      font-size: 20px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="rockChoice isRock"><a href="#">Rock</a></div>
  <div class="scissorsChoice"><a href="#">Scissors</a></div>
  <div class="paperChoice"><a href="#">Paper</a></div>
  <script>
    var userChoice;
    function checkUserChoice() {
      if (document.querySelector(".rockChoice").classList.contains("isRock")) {
        userChoice = "rock";
      } else if (document.querySelector(".scissorsChoice").classList.contains("isScissors")) {
        userChoice = "scissors";
      } else if (document.querySelector(".paperChoice").classList.contains("isPaper")) {
        userChoice = "paper";
      }
    }

    checkUserChoice();
    console.log('the user choice is ' + userChoice);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your through and knowledgeable answer!

Answer (score 0):

`classList.contains` method excepted a string and you are passing string as a variable.

Use `document.querySelector(".rockChoice").classList.contains('isRock')`